# How do I write this react js code with 'eventHandlerWithThrottling'?

Tags: reactjs

**Task:**
We have a function called makeRequest that makes an API request.
We also have a function called eventHandler that is hooked up to
an event (a click, for example), and right now it's a dumb handler
that simply calls makeRequest.

Write a new event handler eventHandlerWithThrottling that we can hook
up to the click event such that it won't call makeRequest more
than once every 5 seconds. We do not care what the API request returns (assume it's a fire-and-forgot POST)

Events that occur within 5 seconds of an API request are "remembered",
and once the 5 second timeout is over, **the latest one will be fired**.

'''

```
let now = 0;

function makeRequest(payload) {
  // let's pretend this makes a request, and logs the payload/time of request
  console.log({
    data: payload,
    time: Math.round((new Date().getTime() - now) / 1000)
  });
}

const throttle = (callback, delay) => payload => callback(payload);
// const throttledMakeRequest = throttle(makeRequest, 5000);

/*** TESTS (do not edit) **/
{
  // set "now" to the moment when tests started
  now = new Date().getTime();

  // util function for testing
  function simulateEvent(fn, payload, timeOfEvent) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      fn(payload);
    }, timeOfEvent);
  }

  function test(name, timeout, code) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.groupEnd();
      console.group(name);
      code();
    }, timeout);
  }

  console.clear();
  // ADDED first case. just one call
  test("test 1: hello", 0, () => {
    const eventHandlerWithThrottling1 = throttle(makeRequest, 50);
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling1, "1. hello", 0); // hello logged at 0
  });

  //  2. 'hello' (t = 0), 'goodbye' (t = 5)
  test("test 2: hello, goodbye", 60, () => {
    const eventHandlerWithThrottling2 = throttle(makeRequest, 50);
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling2, "2. hello", 0); // hello logged at 0
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling2, "2. goodbye", 40); // goodbye logged at 5
  });

  // 3. a (t = 0), 'c' (t = 5), 'd' (t = 10)
  test("test 3: a, c, d", 160, () => {
    const eventHandlerWithThrottling3 = throttle(makeRequest, 50);
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling3, "3. a", 0); // a logged at 0
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling3, "3. b", 20); // ignored
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling3, "3. c", 40); // c logged at 5
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling3, "3. d", 70); // d logged at 10
  });

  // ADDED 4.
  test("test 4: a, c, d, e, f, g", 300, () => {
    const eventHandlerWithThrottling4 = throttle(makeRequest, 50);
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling4, "4. a", 0); // a logged at 0
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling4, "4. b", 20); // ignored
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling4, "4. c", 40); // c logged at 5
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling4, "4. d", 70); // d logged at 10
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling4, "4. e", 200); // e logged at 20. like if it was first call
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling4, "4. f", 220); // f called at 25
    simulateEvent(eventHandlerWithThrottling4, "4. g", 260); // g logged at 30
  });
}
```

'''

Comment: in short you just want to stop rendering this component after 5 seconds ?

Comment: You just want to render this component once for 5 second , am I correct?

Comment: @NihalChandwani Yes and Also 'Events that occur within 5 seconds of an API request are "remembered", and once the 5 second timeout is over, the latest one will be fired.'

Comment: to be remembered , I have idea of storing data via state in local Storage and as far as render timer is concerned , make a render state initially false , and use setTimOut function to render it by changing the state true after respective seconds.... to be more clear of what i m saying , I will post code as soon as possible

Comment: its somewhat difficult for me to understand your code, please just let me know what exactly you code for??    ....... You may clear the scenario  diagrammatically , will be easier for us to understand

Comment: and what i found that , delay parameter isn't used,  when you call throttle function , it takes just takes one parameter and hence delay is not used.... coz you defined just payload in callback